# Django templates and markdown

Tags: django, django-templates, markdown

Suppose I have a Django template written in Markdown.

Does it make sense to process the markdown first, and then render the template, or should I render the template, and then send it through the Markdown filter?

From a computation standpoint the first is preferable, as I'm going to be rendering the template in a loop. I'm just wondering if there are some possible drawbacks I'm not thinking of.

Some code for reference:

```
import markdown
from django import template

# Here, template_content_md would actually come from the database
template_content_md = """
{{ obj.title }}
-----------
**{{ obj.author }}**

(more Markdown content here using variables)

[More info]({{ obj.get_absolute_url }})
"""

output_list = []

# first method
template_content_html = markdown.markdown(template_content_md)
for obj in object_list:
    tt = template.Template(template_content_html)
    content_html = tt.render(Context({'obj': obj}))
    output_list.append(content_html)

#second method
for obj in object_list:
    tt = template.Template(template_content_md)
    content_md = tt.render(Context({'obj': obj}))
    content_html = markdown.markdown(content_md)
    output_list.append(content_html)
```

As you can see, in the second version, `markdown.markdown` is run once for each `obj` in `object_list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since what you are **generating** from the Markdown-formatted content is a Django template it makes the most sense to use your first method (generate HTML from the Markdown template and then use the generated Django template in a loop).

As well as being faster, that also ensures that nothing in `obj` is accidentally translated into HTML by Markdown.

I would *also* "cache" the Django template:

```
template_content_html = markdown.markdown(template_content_md)
# Only generate the template once
tt = template.Template(template_content_html)

for obj in object_list:
    content_html = tt.render(Context({'obj': obj}))
    output_list.append(content_html)
```

Comment: Actually just remembered one case where this is a problem: I'm using the urlize function to auto-highlight links in the Markdown (for example, in the template it would be `{{ obj.author.email }}`, rendered to `email@domain.org` and then translated to `<a href="mailto:email@domain.org">email@domain.org</a>` by Markdown. I'm using a couple of other Markdown filters like this too, so I'll just have to see if I can duplicate that functionality after doing the template rendering.